# Error "no valid rapl domains found in package 0" when boot ubuntu 16.04 installed in virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed the Ubuntu in virtualbox for months.
After I upgrade the Linux kernal, I cannot boot Ubuntu with normal mode.
But it can success boot in recovery mode
I occurred some error:

1. **floppy0: no floppy controllers found.**  => this will let me wait a few minutes, and it will go through.
2. **intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0**  =>the boot process stuck at this error

I don't know whether it's a problem whit kernal 4.72 or not.

Linux kernal: 4.72 lowlatency amd64
virtualbox version: 5.14
physic cpu: x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.

Below is my method:

> 1.Enter recovery mode.
>
> 2.Install generic version kernel
>
> 3.Purge all of the lowlatency kernels

But I still don't know why virtualbox can't run with lowlatency version kernel.

And the error (or normal boot process),"**intel_rapl: no vaild rapl domains found in package 0**", is still showed when boot, but it dosen't let the boot process stop.