# Vagrant stuck trying to start up: No valid rapl domains found

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I am running Homestead via Vagrant, I have just updated my box and tried to start it. I get the following log:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

I have enabled the GUI to see if its waiting for some sort of prompt and I see this message:

> intel_repl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0.

Can someone advise how I can fix this?

EDIT: I am using Mac OS Yosemite.

Comment: Sounds like a bad box.

Comment: I now have two boxes, the existing one and the new one. I have deleted the new box and tried to run the existing box but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you provide more information, please copy your Vagrantfile and if you have any provisioning running

Comment: I don't think that message is the reason Vagrant can't SSH to the box, sounds like it's harmless: https://askubuntu.com/questions/449574/intel-rapl-no-valid-rapl-domains-message-upon-boot

Comment: had the same problem now, my first problem is VT-x/AMD and need to enable intel virtualization technology in bios, but after i enabled that, this is my next problem. intel rapl is Running average power limit, dont know why this happen, my first laptop work properly with intel i3 5th gen, but my laptop now is i5 6th gen, and i dont know why its not working here. i need help for this also

Comment: Related: [Error “no valid rapl domains found in package 0” when boot ubuntu 16.04 installed in virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121129/error-no-valid-rapl-domains-found-in-package-0-when-boot-ubuntu-16-04-installe)

Answer (score 0):

**I am posting this here, because I can't add a comment** (only 47 rep atm).

I had a problem very similar to yours (if not the same) 2 years ago. I discovered that the reason I had that problem with vagrant, was because I used CCleaner to clear all the temp files from my computer. I'm afraid my problem didn't have a fix, so I had to start all over again. I really hope this is not your case, but I'm just saying, this might have happened.